# OpenAPI reuse part of definition without defining a new one

Tags: swagger, models, specifications, openapi, definitions

Suppose that I have this definition in a yaml OpenApi definition

```
definitions:
  User:
    description: "User"
    type: "object"
    properties:
      firstname:
        type: "string"
      lastname:
        type: "string"
      password:
        type: "string"
      email:
        type: "string"
      username:
        type: "string"
```

If in a parameters specification I need specific fields of a definition how can I refer them without defining another model as below?

```
definitions:
  UserLogin:
    description: "User"
    type: "object"
    properties:
      password:
        type: "string"
      email:
        type: "string"
```

Answer (score 2):

*In your question, you are using `definitions` keyword what hints that your question is about [OpenAPI v2 aka. Swagger](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/versions/2.0.md). For [OpenAPI v3](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/versions/3.0.0.md), definitions provided below should be defined inside appropriate [Components Object](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/versions/3.0.0.md#components-object) sections.*

In order to achieve this, you have to use [Composition](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/versions/2.0.md#composition-and-inheritance-polymorphism) with keyword `allOf`. There is a great example that relates to your question [here](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/versions/2.0.md#models-with-composition). First, you have to define a smaller object and then include it into the definition of a larger as follows:

```
definitions:
  UserLogin:
    description: User Login
    type: object
    properties:
      password:
        type: string
      email:
        type: string
  User:
    allOf:
    - $ref: '#/definitions/UserLogin'
    - description: User
      type: object
      properties:
        firstname:
          type: string
        lastname:
          type: string
        username:
          type: string
```

It is worth noting that:

- Some lighter implementations may not support `allOf` keyword.
- Using composition may increase or decrease the readability of the documentation, depending on the complexity and choice of words used to name the schemas.